# Like/Dislike function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

[image: like/dislike at same time]

I have this ajax function of liking and disliking a comment but with this function, I can like and dislike at the same time. for example When I like the comment it is liking it and if after that I dislike it does that too without removing my like.

Here is the code for like (upvote) and dislike (downvote)

*up votes*

```
$(".tup").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var reviewId = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: document.location.origin + '/review/' + reviewId + '/upvote',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                review_id: reviewId
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function (data) {

            if (data == true) {
                $('.tup[data-id=' + reviewId + '] .vn').text(function (i, oldVal)
                 {
                    return parseInt(oldVal, 10) + 1;
                });
            } else {
                snackybar.timer("Already Voted", 3000);
            }

        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        });
});

// down votes

$(".tdown").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var reviewId = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: document.location.origin + '/review/' + reviewId + '/downvote',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                review_id: reviewId
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            if (data == true) {
                $('.tdown[data-id=' + reviewId + '] .vn').text(function (i, oldVal) {
                    return parseInt(oldVal, 10)  + 1;
                });
            } else {
                snackybar.timer("Already Voted", 3000);
            }
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        });
});
```

And this is the controller's code

```
 public function upvote($id) {
    if(!UpDownVote::where('review_id',$id)->where('upvote',1)->first()) {
        Review::findOrFail($id)->increment('upvote');
        UpDownVote::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'review_id' => $id,
            'upvote' => 1
        ]);
        return 'true';
    } else {
        return 'false';
    }
}

public function downvote($id) {
    if(!UpDownVote::where('review_id',$id)->where('downvote',1)->first()) {
        Review::findOrFail($id)->increment('downvote');
        UpDownVote::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'review_id' => $id,
            'downvote' => 1
        ]);
        return 'true';
    } else {
        return 'false';
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are facing?

Comment: when I'm liking the comment its doing that and after that if I dislike it (press thumbs down) it is doing that as well
which means I can like and dislike a comment at the same time

Comment: please post your HTML code too

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your Ajax calls are asynchronous; thus, when clicking on `tup` button and then the `tdown` one, perhas the treatment have not been done already when you click on the second button.

You can disabled the possibility of clicking when you are waiting for the server response.

```
var isClicking = false;
$(".tup").click(function (e) {
if(isClicking){
   return;
}
isClicking = true;
e.preventDefault();
var reviewId = $(this).data('id');

$.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: document.location.origin + '/review/' + reviewId + '/upvote',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            review_id: reviewId
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function (data) {

        if (data == true) {
            $('.tup[data-id=' + reviewId + '] .vn').text(function (i, oldVal)
             {
                return parseInt(oldVal, 10) + 1;
            });
        } else {
            snackybar.timer("Already Voted", 3000);
        }

    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    }).always(function(){
     isClicking=false;
  });
});

// down votes




 $(".tdown").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
if(isClicking){
   return;
}
isClicking = true;
var reviewId = $(this).data('id');

$.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: document.location.origin + '/review/' + reviewId + '/downvote',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            review_id: reviewId
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        if (data == true) {
            $('.tdown[data-id=' + reviewId + '] .vn').text(function (i, oldVal) {
                return parseInt(oldVal, 10)  + 1;
            });
        } else {
            snackybar.timer("Already Voted", 3000);
        }
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    }).always(function(){
     isClicking=false;
  });
});
```